# .nav > li OR .nav li to style all lists inside .nav class

Tags: css, class, selector

Which is the correct selector to select all li items inside .nav class ?

Have tried both and they seem to both work. Want to know what the correct way of writing the selector

Trying to style all list items inside .nav class. I know its a basic question but all sites say something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by selecting all childs:

- **.nav li**: This is called [Decendand combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), which selects all `li` that has an ancestor with class `.nav`, no matter if there are intermediate layers between.
- **.nav > li**: This is called [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator), which only selects the immediate child elements under`.nav`. (For example, `.nav > ol > li` won't be selected)

```css
.nav li {
  color: red;
}

.nav>li {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">

  <li>Direct Child</li>
  
  <ol>
    <li>Not Direct Child</li>
  </ol>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `.nav li` would be best. If you're using `<ul>` elements around your `<li>` elements then the `.nav > li` won't select them, because it only looks for li elements that are first-layer children of .nav elements instead of all `<li>` elements under something with class `.nav` Might be of help to read these pages on css selectors to explain:

[w3schools css selector guide](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php)

[mdn web docs "descendant combinator" css selector explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator)